# Rails - How to minimize these queries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization

I need to minimize database queries in a view. First lets look at my setup: (Question at the end)

My models:

```
- User has_many Followings
- Following belongs_to Show/User
- Show has_many Episodes
```

FollowingsController:

```
Following.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_id => current_user.id }, :include => [:show], :order => "shows.name")
```

Show model:

```
def prev_episode()
    Episode.find(:first, :conditions => ["show_id = ? AND air_date < ?", self.id, Date.today], :order => "air_date desc, number desc")
end

def next_episode()
    Episode.find(:first, :conditions => ["show_id = ? AND air_date >= ?", self.id, Date.today], :order => "air_date asc, number asc")
end
```

My view (simplified):

```
  <% @followings.each do |following| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to "#{following.show.name}", show_path(:permalink => following.show.permalink) %></strong></td>
    <td><%= following.show.prev_episode # UNWANTED QUERY %></td>
    <td><%= following.show.next_episode # UNWANTED QUERY %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

This makes an **awful** lot of queries per request.
This view can contain up to 100 rows, which makes over 200 requests!
I really need to minimize this. Any ideas?

PS. I can use memcached if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this would be to have each episode have a previous episode and a following episode linked as foreign keys, which will save the date search.  The downside to this approach is going to be that you'll need to link episodes as they are added, but there's no free lunch...